# show div when another div is shown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have menu that opens a dropdown on click. The dropdown div is set to display none, and changes the class when the menu item is clicked. I also have another div that has display:none and I want to show this div when the dropdown is showed. How do I do this with javascript?

The html:

1. Hidden Div I wanna show.
2. Hidden dropdown menu
3. The menubutton that shows nr 2.

   ```
    1.<div id="site-overlay">
    2.<div id="dropdown_fullwidth">
    3.<a href="#_" class="megamenu_drop">Computers</a>
   ```

Comment: Fiddle that shows the hidden div (nr1) on click:    http://jsfiddle.net/Jerryskate/doxdmxmL/2/

Comment: Unfortunately, this is off-topic for SO. If you show some JS that you have tried, it becomes more on topic.

Comment: Not sure this is off-topic, as tjons suggests, but it might need a bit of narrowing down as there are lots of ways of ding this : 1) Give both DIVs another (same) class which has display:none, and set the class active or disabled. that'll affect anytghing that has that class. 2)  Trap the event that sets the dic to be un-hidden and run some js to do the same thing to your second div (most obvious solution) and 3) put the second div inside the first div but with a style of absolute or relative and give it top/right style attributes that put it in the right place.

Comment: You probably need to say a bit more about the event that hides/unhides the div because as it stands, adding some javascript in that event to do the same thing to the second div is the (really) obvious answer .. is there some problem with that ?

Comment: Hmm. Didn't realized it was Offtopic. what I have tried is inside the fiddle. I thought show the div on menuclick would work, but it became wrong when I started clicking around on several menuitems, so show it when the dropdown shows would be ideal.

Comment: Seems like the script for the menu ads a active and noactive class to the element. heres the script: https://jsfiddle.net/Jerryskate/ts2kn0bn/